# R_using nlsLM() with constraints

Tags: r, constraints, nls

I am using `nlsLM {minpack.lm}` to find the values of parameters `a` and `b` of function `myfun` which give the best fit for the data set, `mydata`.

```
mydata=data.frame(x=c(0,5,9,13,17,20),y = c(0,11,20,29,38,45))

myfun=function(a,b,r,t){
  prd=a*b*(1-exp(-b*r*t))
  return(prd)
}
```

and using `nlsLM`

```
myfit=nlsLM(y~myfun(a,b,r=2,t=x),data=mydata,start=list(a=2000,b=0.05),
                  lower = c(1000,0), upper = c(3000,1))
```

It works. But now I would like to introduce a constraint which is `a*b<1000`. I had a look at the option available in `nlsLM` to set constraint via `nls.lm.control`. But it's not much of help. can somebody help me here or suggest a different method to to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my knowledge, in nlsLM of minpack.lm package lower and upper parameter bounds are the only available constrains.  
One possible solution to your problem is based on the use of the package `nloptr`, an R interface to the free open-source library **NLopt** for nonlinear optimization.
In the code below I use `cobyla`, an algorithm for derivative-free optimization with nonlinear inequality and equality constraints:

```
mydata <- data.frame(x=c(0,5,9,13,17,20), y=c(0,11,20,29,38,45))

myfun=function(a,b,r,t){
  prd=a*b*(1-exp(-b*r*t))
  return(prd)
}

library(nloptr)

sse <- function(ab,r,x,y){
   sum((y - myfun(ab[1],ab[2],r,x))^2)
}

nonlincons <- function(ab,r,x,y) {
   h <- numeric(1)
   h[1] <-  1000 - ab[1]*ab[2]
   return(h)
}

x0 <- c(2000,0.05)
optpar <- cobyla(x0=x0, fn=sse, lower = c(1000,0), upper = c(3000,1), 
                 hin=nonlincons, r=2, x=mydata$x, y=mydata$y, 
                 control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-12, maxeval = 20000))
(optpar <- optpar$par)

sum((mydata$y-myfun(optpar[1],optpar[2],r=2,mydata$x))^2)
```

The values of the optimal parameters are:

```
[1] 3.000000e+03 2.288303e-02
```

and the sum of squared errors is:

```
[1] 38.02078
```

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `nlsLM` doesn't accept constraints, one possible method is to use `constrOptim` function instead, but the drawback is that you have to turn the problem into the form that `constrOptim` accepts. By the way, I'm currently working on an R package that gives a nice interface for `optim` and `constrOptim` and make necessary transformation automatically, but it is not ready to use yet. Here is how to use `constrOptim` for this problem.

The first step is that `constrOptim` only accepts linear constraints,
`a * b < 1000` => `log(a) + log(b) < log(1000)`, so you need to reparametrize the problem using `log(a)` and `log(b)`, the constraints becomes: `-log(a) - log(b) > -log(1000)`, `log(a) >= log(1000)`, `-log(a) >= -log(3000)`, `-log(b) >= 0`, `ui` and `ci` are matrix form for these constraints. And `myfun1` is the reparametrize version for your function, and then you can use `constrOptim` to obtain your solution for `log(a)` and `log(b)`.

```
mydata=data.frame(x=c(0,5,9,13,17,20),y = c(0,11,20,29,38,45))

myfun=function(a,b,r,t){
    prd=a*b*(1-exp(-b*r*t))
    return(prd)
}

myfun1 <- function(logab, data){
    sum((data$y - myfun(exp(logab[1]), exp(logab[2]), r = 2, t = data$x)) ^ 2)
}

ui <- rbind(c(-1,-1), c(1,0), c(-1,0), c(0,-1))
ci <- c(-log(1000), log(1000), -log(3000), 0)
init <- log(c(2000, 0.05))
r <- constrOptim(theta = init, f = myfun1, grad = NULL, ui = ui, ci = ci, data = mydata)
```